# Add a fragment to the URL without causing a redirect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

Is there is a way how to add hash # to my URL without redirect?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

```
window.location.hash = 'something';
```

That is just plain JavaScript.

Your comment...

> Hi, what I really need is to add only the hash... something like this: `window.location.hash = '#';` but in this way nothing is added.

Try this...

```
window.location = '#';
```

Also, don't forget about the `window.location.replace()` method.

Comment: HI, what i really need is to add only hash... something like this: window.location.hash = '#'; but in this way nothing is added..

Comment: If you want to add a hash without it being stored in the browser history, use `window.history.replaceState(undefined, undefined, "#hash_value")` or `window.location.replace(String url)`.

Answer (score 29):

For straight HTML, with no JavaScript required:

```
<a href="#something">Add '#something' to URL</a>
```

Or, to take your question more literally, to just add '#' to the URL:

```
<a href="#">Add '#' to URL</a>
```

Comment: not correct, as you need to click the link to change the hash.. so you are missing the js part where you trigger the "click"..

Comment: @Juan Why do we need to "trigger" a click? The original question just asked how we can add the `#` to the URL. Actually clicking a link as I suggested will fulfil that. No JS necessary.

Comment: Your answer describes how to create a link that, WHEN clicked, adds a fragment to the url. The question asks how to add a fragment. So your answer is missing the action, that is, the "click"

Comment: Fair enough, I can see the question being interpreted that way. Hopefully someone will still find this option useful for their use case.

Answer (score 14):

```
window.location.hash = 'whatever';
```

Comment: The `#` prefix is not required.

Comment: @alex: Ah, I wasn't too sure whether it was required or not. window.location.hash returns the hash with a # prefix, so I assumed it was. Thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: No worries - and it makes you wonder why it always returns it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var URL = "scratch.mit.edu/projects";
var mainURL = window.location.pathname;

if (mainURL == URL) {
    mainURL += ( mainURL.match( /[\?]/g ) ? '&' : '#' ) + '_bypasssharerestrictions_';
    console.log(mainURL)
}
```