# jQuery Tools: Accordion, with #link for backbutton?

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, jquery-tools

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/accordion.html

Is there a way to take this accordion and allow for hash tags for browser history?

Answer (score 1):

Reference this post for the Jquery event you are looking for `window.location.hash = 'something';`

If you add that to each event / click you should be able to hardlink to it in the URL

[Add a fragment to the URL without causing a redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282069/update-url-add-hash-without-redirect)