# How to disable jQuery Mobile scrolling to top of the page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have some anchors in the page and when I load page using anchor:

```
http://localhost:1820/Home/FAQ#question4
```

jQuery Mobile after 1-3 seconds automatically scrolls to top of the page. I cannot add fix to `$(document).ready()` because this event fires before scrolling (scrolling appear after all content is loaded - with additional social button images, scripts etc.).

When I removing jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js script - bug disappears.
When I removing all scripts except jQuery and jQuery mobile - bug still exists. So the problem should be in jQuery Mobile script.

How can I solve problem?

I used Chrome and Opera to test it.

P.S. I set `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;`, so my site do not use Ajax to load pages.

Answer (score 1):

jQueryMobile uses by default the '#' character to indicate pages, not anchors (see section "Linking within a multi-page document" in the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html)).

Try adding `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"` to the link to the page, as described in the documentation.

Comment: This bug appears even if I directly enter URL address to my browser navigation bar, without using links.

Comment: You will need to give the id "question4" to the `div` with `data-role="page"` that you want to display with the URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.mobile.silentScroll()
```

Can be a solution to your problems.You can catch the Hash section at page load and use it to automatically scroll to the section where you need to take your page to. I answered a similar question recently. See if it helps you
[jQuery Mobile Tabs and Anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181586/jquery-mobile-tabs-and-anchors/12182868#12182868)