# Several forms with OnChange event

Tags: javascript, php, onchange

I have a drop-down list and an input field. 
I would like the URL to change as soon as the drop-down list is modified.

```
<?php $s = $_GET["s"]; $q = $_GET["q"]; ?>
<form method="get" action="" name="formulaire" >
   <input type="text" name="q" value="<?php echo $q; ?>" />
   <select name="s" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
   <option <?php if ( $s == 'opt1' ) { echo 'value="opt1" selected="selected" >opt1 '; } else { echo 'value="opt1" >opt1 '; } ?></option>
   <option <?php if ( $s == 'opt2' ) { echo 'value="opt2" selected="selected" >opt2 '; } else { echo 'value="opt2" >opt2 '; } ?></option>
   <option <?php if ( $s == 'opt3' ) { echo 'value="opt3" selected="selected" >opt3 '; } else { echo 'value="opt3" >opt3 '; } ?></option>
   </select>
</form>
```

As it is now, it runs only if the input field is filled before the list. I tried to replace `value="opt1"` by `value="?s=opt1"`. But when the input field is filled, the URL is like this `?q=test&s=%3Fs%3Dopt1`.

Here are the URL I'm expecting :

If only the text area is filled : `?q=text`

If only the drop-down list is selected : `?s=opt1`

If the input field and the drop-down list are both filled/selected : `?q=texte&s=opt1`

Here is an example : http://arkhana.fr/tempstack/menudyn.php

Comment: By textarea you mean the input field?

Comment: OK, sorry, I mean an input field. I've just edited my post.

Comment: When you set `window.location.href` you cause page to redirect to the give address. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282069/add-a-fragment-to-the-url-without-causing-a-redirect

Comment: OK, I've just edited my example... But is it still possible to get the parameters with GET method as soon as something is changed ? and how can I do the same with the input field ?

Comment: Your sample only sets hash. I don't think it reloads the page. Do you want the new url to be without hash, ie. only url parameters?

Comment: I have two parameters `q` and `s` that I want to be sent to the page through `GET` method because it changes the content of the page (see my sample page). I know to do this. But I want also the drop-down list to be dynamic (thought it was possible with `OnChange`). And as it is, it sends `q` OR `s` but not `q` AND `s` (and `s` is not sent properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use select onchange="loadUrl()". Assumes option value="opt1" like above... without "?=" etc that I see ATM on your sample page.

Put following script on the page:

```
function loadUrl() {
  var params = [];
  var inpVal = document.getElementsByName("q")[0].value;
  if (inpVal.length) params.push("q="+inpVal);
  var selVal = document.getElementsByName("s")[0].value;
  if (selVal.length) params.push("s="+selVal);

  window.location.search = params.join("&");
 }
```

Comment: It's almost good, thank you. The last problem is that the select button of the list always tries to close (see my sample page). 
And sorry, I don't know what is ATM ?

Comment: ATM = at the moment... I saw you had changed your code. And yeah I changed a bug ;)